# how i can use JSON result in calculation in php

Tags: php, json

i want to use json result in some calculation but whatever i try it didn't work.

```
<?php 

//product id
$gp_id=$_GET['gp_id'];

//Importing the database connection 
require_once('dbConnect.php');

    $sql2 = "SELECT sum(rating_score) AS total_rate ,count(consumer_id) AS consumer
            FROM productrate 
            WHERE gp_id='$gp_id'";

    //Getting result 
    $result = mysql_query($sql2); 

    //Adding results to an array 
    $res = array(); 

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        array_push($res, array(
          // "gp_id"=>$row['gp_id'],
            "total_rate"=>$row['total_rate'],
            "consumer"=>$row['consumer']
            )
); }

    //Displaying the array in json format 
    $objJson=json_encode($res);
    echo $objJson;

//calculate avg rate of specific product
$avg_rate =  (int)"total_rate" /  (int)"consumer";
echo  $avg_rate ;

?>
```

as you see at the end i try to do some calculation but it didn't work.

this is the output... 
[{"total_rate":"18","consumer":"4"}]
Warning: Division by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\totalrate\highRate.php on line 33

Comment: Can you describe how the calculation didn't work? Do you get any error? Posting this information would help someone help you!

Comment: @DevrajGadhavi Warning: [Division by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\totalrate\highRate.php on line 33] This is the error i get

Answer (score 0):

`$objJson=json_encode($res);` makes json string. For example `'{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}'`. You cannot use it like variables. Its string.

Answer (score 0):

```
$avg_rate = "total_rate" / "consumer";
```

Looks like you trying to divide a string with another string.
Try using the array element instead, like:

```
$avg_rate = $res["total_rate"] / $res["consumer"];
```

Comment: Try using `$res[index]["total_rate"]` and `$res[index]["consumer"]`. You will have to put whatever index will work for you. As your question is quite vague, I won't be able to help much than that. If you don't know what index to put, try `die(var_dump($res))` to have a look at the structure of your data, and isolate what you want to extrat / calculate

Comment: thank you, i solve the problem, and i post my solution here

Answer (score 0):

finally i solve the problem ...

```
 //product id
$gp_id=$_GET['gp_id'];

//Importing the database connection 
 require_once('dbConnect.php');

$sql2 = "SELECT sum(rating_score) AS total_rate ,count(consumer_id) AS consumer
        FROM productrate 
        WHERE gp_id='$gp_id'";
//Getting result 
$result = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());

//Adding results to an array 
$res = array(); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
        array_push($res, array(
        "avg_rate"=>$row['total_rate']/ $row['consumer'],
        "total_rate"=>$row['total_rate'],
        "consumer"=>$row['consumer']
        )
     ); }

//Displaying the array in json format 
$objJson=json_encode($res);
echo $objJson;
 ?>
```